# maven build fail in linux

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-war-plugin

This could be a nothing for an experienced developer. However, iam having this problem when trying to build my project in linux environment(Red Hat). It gives me following error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on project ABC: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1]
```

However, it works perfectly in windows environment.

Here is my Pom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ABC</artifactId>
    <name>ABC</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>  
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
        <java-simplified-encryption-version>1.9.0</java-simplified-encryption-version>
        <mysql-version>5.1.19</mysql-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>       

        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ~~~~ -->
        <!-- Java Simplified Encryption -->
        <!-- ~~~~ -->
         <dependency>
              <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
              <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
              <version>${java-simplified-encryption-version}</version>
              <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ~~~~~ -->
        <!-- UTILS -->
        <!-- ~~~~~ -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <!-- Replace with the version of the MySQL driver you want to use -->
            <version>${mysql-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MemCache -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>spy</groupId>
            <artifactId>spymemcached</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>ABC</warName>
                </configuration>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>

        <!--  Memcache -->
        <repository>
            <id>spy</id>
            <name>Spy Repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>


        <repository>
            <id>Maven Cetral Repo</id>
            <name>Maven Cetral Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring security</id>
            <name>spring security Repository</name>
            <url>http://http.git.springsource.org/spring-security/spring-security.git</url>
        </repository>

        <!-- Obtaining Spring Releases From The Enterprise Bundle Repository (EBR) -->
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
            <name>EBR Spring Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
            <name>EBR External Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

    </repositories>
</project>
```

And this is my web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>ABC</display-name>    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Un-comment following section when deploy with tomcat -->

    <!-- <resource-ref>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/abctDB</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref> -->

</web-app>
```

This is my rest-servlet

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"      
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd         
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context         
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd                          
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">  


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

    <bean id="jsonViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
    </bean> 


    <bean name="ABCController" class="com.abc.mvp.controller.ABCController" />




    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

Appreciate if someone can show me why i cannot build my application in linux environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found the cause. 
It is just i have missed to include web.xml configuration in war plugin

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>               
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                 <webXml>src\main\webApp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Strange...